Bimodule endomorphisms of a bimodule over a noncommutative ring
Let $R$ be a noncommutative ring and $M$ an $R$-$R$-bimodule that is projective as left $R$-module. We know that the bimodule of left $R$-module endomorphisms ${}_REnd(M)$ is isomorphic to the tensor product $M^* \otimes_R M$, where $M^*$ is the bimodule of left $R$-module maps from $M$ to $R$. Does there exists an analogous description of ${}_REnd_R(M)$, the space of $R$-$R$-bimodule maps from $M$ to itself when we assume that $M$ is projective as a left and as a right bimodule.

Your first claim (about the tensor product) is obviously wrong, as witnessed by any torsion module. For example, $\Bbb Z/p$ over $\Bbb Z$.

I have added the assumption of projectivity to fix this.

. . .  this of course excludes your counterexample of a torsion module.
